# What could have caused these cracks on the ceiling and wall?

Tags: walls, ceiling, crack, cracks

Today I went to inspect an an unit which I want to buy but I am concerned as there are visible cracks on the walls and ceiling. The unit is located on the top floor of a 3 storey unit building, is made out of brick, and it looks like it is 25 year old.
What I noticed is that the bathroom and kitchen need to be repaired as water is constantly running, and taps are leaking, so the environment feels that is moist. Most likely I was thinking I might need to renovate, but the most concerning part are the cracks on the ceiling and walls. Pictures attached.
Can anyone give me some advice, please? I am wondering if it is an structural damage.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Crack on the wall in one of the bedrooms]

[image: Crack on the corridor]

[image: Crack on the corridor]

[image: Crack on the corridor]

[image: Crack in the other bedroom]

Comment: Building movement - high winds or foundations moving. What did your building surveyor say in their report?

Comment: Hmm this was my first inspection, and the agent only said it is made out of briks

Comment: Don't rely on your agent.  Their primary duty (unless you engaged one as a buyer's agent) is to the seller.  At the very least, have a home inspection done.  But I'll bet the typical inspector will pass as to the cause of the cracks you've shown.  You need a structural engineer to evaluate.

Comment: And YES, it looks like settlement to me.  Too many cracks in too many places to be a case of a twisted stud or something like that.  Does the foundation show any cracks?

Comment: Is the home or building 25 years old or the cracks? I haven’t seen that kind of coving / crown molding since the 50’s and most was pre 20’s where is the building located in the world?.

Comment: thanks for the replies, this is in Australia. The building is 25 years old.

Comment: I had a look around the building it didn't look that it had other cracks.